# GETTER does not return data when entering a URL

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, getter

I work with Nuxt.js

And I want to know why if I enter the INDEX page everything is running fine

And if I click a link to an ID page, everything works fine

**But** if I go directly to the ID page (via URL) I don't see content from VUEX - the GETTER does not return data

https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-burnell-h4wz7

Comment: You are dispatching the Action only in the Categories page, not inside the category details page. when you visit the page directly the state is empty. 
"this.$store.dispatch('categories/fetchAll');"

Comment: and when you navigate between pages using nuxt-link the state will persist unless you reload the page.

Comment: How can I identify if the user is directly entering the page

Comment: You can check the state value and if that is not set you can dispatch the action on each necessary page.

Comment: I added this section https://codepen.io/SGUserFace/pen/mdJmGNB.js But if I get into an ID that doesn't exist I have no end of dispatch